# What do we do to get our custom theme?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So, now that we are no longer [in Beta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/new-beta-theme-launched), what is the next step for getting a custom theme? From what I understand, this used to be an automatic thing when sites graduated, with Stack Overflow's official designer creating something with the input of the community. Do we get something similar?

Someone was [asking in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52679874#52679874), and I realized I didn't know the answer.

Comment: That "someone" is me! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realize that our designation of "no longer in beta" =/= "graduated". Stack Exchange wanted to recognize sites that function well, but don't meet the requirements for a full graduation (Mostly the 10 questions per day metric).

What it means:

- Beta is removed from the site name
- Moderator elections will occur (eventually)
- Closed without comment flag (for moderators) goes away
- Area 51 tag - Launched instead of Beta

A couple of key items that it does *not* mean:

- Reputation requirements remain at beta levels (For example, trusted user and analytics kick in at 4k and 5k rep respectively. On a full graduated site, those kick in at 20k and 25k respectively).
- Themes remain the province of fully graduated sites.

This change was not a graduation per se, but recognition that a site can function well, even if it doesn't meet graduation requirements. This is a natural follow-on from the announcement a few years ago that a site that had adequate moderation was in no danger of being closed any longer. Eventually theming may occur, but it's not planned any time in the near future.

Comment: How many questions do we get in a day JohnP? Is it less than 1?

Comment: They post the metrics pretty regularly in Meta. And... yeah.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Oh, sorry I didn't know.

Comment: We'd like to get those metrics higher, but it's hard to do so organically.

Comment: @RoundHouse And I was wrong... we haven't updated those stats since we left Beta - https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/keeping-track-of-our-statistics

Comment: So, anything I need to know? Are you guys doing anything out of the ordinary to get more participation/involvement from practitioners and trainers? It seems it's going to be difficult to get 10 questions a day. @SeanDuggan

Comment: We had an initiative going on where we were trying to post at least one question a week each, but it kind of petered out.  I honestly don't know if I expect the volume to go up all that much. There aren't a lot of new problems in martial arts.

Answer (score 2):

Custom themes are not imminent.

As far as I know, Stack Exchange's priorities at this point are:

1. [resolving the current controversy involving a moderator removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) If you spend any time on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), this topic has dominated conversation for the past two months.
2. moderator elections for graduated sites. There was some discussion of this being a manual process, and many sites graduated from beta at the same time. There is no clear timetable for when elections will occur.

So in short, do not expect to see a custom theme until after moderator elections.

Comment: The controversy is heading to the courts. It is not going to be resolved soon and should concern all the users of stack. Then again, I might be a little biased here⸮

Comment: @Sardathrion-ReinstateMonica Yes, the whole situation is disappointing. I don't understand at all why this could not be resolved more amicably.

Comment: Ego clashing? Internet drama? People forgetting the gold rule: *do not be a dick!*…